# No connexion on browsers but works with ping

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-connection

I use **Chrome/IE** to connect to the internet, but it does not work. When I ping the url, it works well! Someone can help.
Thank you

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your setup and your question is very generic, but probably it is a problem with the DNS servers, you can reach the IP address but there is no way to translate the addresses you type in the browser bar to ip addresses.

- Configure your routers\firewalls\network interface card with the correct DNS servers.